# MySql join to return three rows per type, regardless of how many rows there are

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to join these two tables I created so that the resultset has 3 entries for each type.

Data table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM data;
+--------------+-----------+
| Labels       | Data      |
+--------------+-----------+
| Component    | 1325.1988 |
| Component    |  554.1652 |
| Component    |  105.4002 |
| Development  |  203.4163 |
| Development  |   59.4500 |
| Development  |   20.4498 |
| Flash Assets |  285.5334 |
| Flash Assets |  302.1501 |
| Flash Assets |   61.1836 |
| Release      |    0.6000 |
| Release      |    2.3666 |
| Repackage    |  416.2169 |
| Repackage    | 5195.0839 |
| Repackage    |    4.5667 |
| Source Diff  |    1.9000 |
| Source Diff  |    0.4000 |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Types table

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM types ORDER BY Labels;
+------------------------+------+
| Labels                 | Data |
+------------------------+------+
| Component              |    0 |
| Component              |    0 |
| Component              |    0 |
| Development            |    0 |
| Development            |    0 |
| Development            |    0 |
| Flash Assets           |    0 |
| Flash Assets           |    0 |
| Flash Assets           |    0 |
| Release                |    0 |
| Release                |    0 |
| Release                |    0 |
| Repackage              |    0 |
| Repackage              |    0 |
| Repackage              |    0 |
| Source Diff            |    0 |
| Source Diff            |    0 |
| Source Diff            |    0 |
+------------------------+------+
```

Current Query:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM data d LEFT JOIN types t on t.Labels = d.Labels;
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------+
| Labels       | Data      | Labels       | Data |
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------+
| Component    | 1325.1988 | Component    |    0 |
| Component    | 1325.1988 | Component    |    0 |
| Component    | 1325.1988 | Component    |    0 |
| Component    |  554.1652 | Component    |    0 |
| Component    |  554.1652 | Component    |    0 |
| Component    |  554.1652 | Component    |    0 |
| Component    |  105.4002 | Component    |    0 |
| Component    |  105.4002 | Component    |    0 |
| Component    |  105.4002 | Component    |    0 |
| Development  |  203.4163 | Development  |    0 |
| Development  |  203.4163 | Development  |    0 |
| Development  |  203.4163 | Development  |    0 |
| Development  |   59.4500 | Development  |    0 |
| Development  |   59.4500 | Development  |    0 |
| Development  |   59.4500 | Development  |    0 |
| Development  |   20.4498 | Development  |    0 |
| Development  |   20.4498 | Development  |    0 |
| Development  |   20.4498 | Development  |    0 |
| Flash Assets |  285.5334 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Flash Assets |  285.5334 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Flash Assets |  285.5334 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Flash Assets |  302.1501 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Flash Assets |  302.1501 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Flash Assets |  302.1501 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Flash Assets |   61.1836 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Flash Assets |   61.1836 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Flash Assets |   61.1836 | Flash Assets |    0 |
| Release      |    0.6000 | Release      |    0 |
| Release      |    0.6000 | Release      |    0 |
| Release      |    0.6000 | Release      |    0 |
| Release      |    2.3666 | Release      |    0 |
| Release      |    2.3666 | Release      |    0 |
| Release      |    2.3666 | Release      |    0 |
| Repackage    |  416.2169 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Repackage    |  416.2169 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Repackage    |  416.2169 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Repackage    | 5195.0839 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Repackage    | 5195.0839 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Repackage    | 5195.0839 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Repackage    |    4.5667 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Repackage    |    4.5667 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Repackage    |    4.5667 | Repackage    |    0 |
| Source Diff  |    1.9000 | Source Diff  |    0 |
| Source Diff  |    1.9000 | Source Diff  |    0 |
| Source Diff  |    1.9000 | Source Diff  |    0 |
| Source Diff  |    0.4000 | Source Diff  |    0 |
| Source Diff  |    0.4000 | Source Diff  |    0 |
| Source Diff  |    0.4000 | Source Diff  |    0 |
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------+
```

My goal with the left join was to get all of the labels from the `Types` table so that there would be Three entries for each label in the resultset. For some reason it comes out funky.

Desired Output:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| Labels       | Data      |
+--------------+-----------+
| Component    | 1325.1988 |
| Component    |  554.1652 |
| Component    |  105.4002 |
| Development  |  203.4163 |
| Development  |   59.4500 |
| Development  |   20.4498 |
| Flash Assets |  285.5334 |
| Flash Assets |  302.1501 |
| Flash Assets |   61.1836 |
| Release      |    0.6000 |
| Release      |    0      |
| Release      |    2.3666 |
| Repackage    |  416.2169 |
| Repackage    | 5195.0839 |
| Repackage    |    4.5667 |
| Source Diff  |    1.9000 |
| Source Diff  |    1.9000 |
| Source Diff  |    0      |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Here there are three entries for each label and the data is replaced with the zeros from the types table

Any help would be great.

Comment: 1) Why you need data column in Types table
2) Consider ID column in Types table and TypeId in Data table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following query:

```
SELECT t.Labels, COALESCE(d.Data, 0) 
FROM data d 
LEFT JOIN types t on t.Labels = d.Labels;
```

1. Why you need data column in Types table
2. Consider ID column in Types table and TypeId in Data table

Comment: These are temporary tables that I have created, that is why they dont have IDs. Also this query gives me the desired number of columns but it doesn't give three entries per label. I still have only two for `Release` and `Source Diff`

Comment: No I'm still only getting two entries for `Release` and `Source Diff`

Comment: Also, `ISNULL(...)` can only take one argument in MySql. Maybe you meant `COALESCE(..)`?

Comment: As long as you have duplicated Labels in table Types your output will be multiplied so each Type.Labels will be outputed to number of the same Data.Labels entry, so when you are build Types table consider DISTINCT keyword when SELECT Labels column from an original table. So - try to build Types table with Unique Labels and then it should work fine

Comment: @Hunter I see you accepted this answer, but does it really work? It seems to me like it will still return 9 rows for types like `Development`.

Comment: @Chris, I didn't seem to get a notice that there was another answer posted. I will look at your post then decide who the answer should go to. I accepted this answer because they were trying the hardest.

Comment: @Hunter If you accept an incorrect answer, there's no way anyone will show up to post the correct one! And you're also hurting the quality of the site; people who find this page later will try the incorrect answer and be frustrated by the check mark. :/ Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @Chris Cunningham: I would suggest to normalize tables instead of using any overkill solutions so this is why suggesting Id ciolumn for Types table and one type entry per table, sorry but query you've provided looks overcomplicated as for me

Comment: @sllev If you think my solution is overkill, feel free to post a comment there to help simplify it. In this comment thread, the right thing to discuss is that the above solution **doesn't work at all**, whether there is one or three copies of each Type in the `Types` table. If there are three, then the solution returns nine records for most types, and if there is only one, then the solution only returns two records for the "Release" type.

Answer (score 0):

your query joined each label to each matching data, ie each of the 3 Components in Types to 3 Components in Data resulting in 9 rows.

You can alternatively do following -

```
Select 
    t.Labels,
    (select column1 from Data d where d.Label = t.Label),
    (select column2 from Data d where d.Label = t.Label),
    (select column3 from Data d where d.Label = t.Label)
from Types t
```

Comment: In Sql Server such subqueries are permitted (Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression). I believe the same should be for MySql?

Comment: -1. This won't provide the correct output; it doesn't even have the correct number of columns as the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: If you ever find yourself `JOIN`ing on something that is not actually a unique ID in some table, you probably want to think about it again.

Here is a somewhat elegant solution to make sure you get three rows for each label:

```
(SELECT d.Labels, d.Data
 FROM Data d)
UNION ALL
(SELECT d.Labels, 0 AS Data
 FROM Data d
 GROUP BY d.Labels
 HAVING Count(*) <= 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT d.Labels, 0 AS Data
 FROM Data d
 GROUP BY d.Labels
 HAVING Count(*) <= 1)
```

By the end, we've added two dummy rows if there was only one to start with, and we've added only one dummy row if there were two to start with. You should always end up with three at the end, like you want.